# A small bit on partial differentials and general solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the equation:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$$

I want to find a general solution.

So I do the following:

$\alpha = ax + bt$, where $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x} = a$, and $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial t} = b$

$\beta = cx + dt$, where $\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x} = c$, and $\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial t} = d$

We do the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial t} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \alpha} + \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial t} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \beta} \text{ and } \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \alpha} + \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \beta} \text{ which is } $$
$$ b \frac{\partial u}{\partial \alpha} + d \frac{\partial u}{\partial \beta} - \left( a \frac{\partial u}{\partial \alpha} + c \frac{\partial u}{\partial \beta}\right)=0 \Rightarrow b \frac{\partial u}{\partial \alpha} + d \frac{\partial u}{\partial \beta} -  a \frac{\partial u}{\partial \alpha} - c \frac{\partial u}{\partial \beta}=0$$
and from there we get 
$$(b -a) \frac{\partial u}{\partial \alpha} + (d-c) \frac{\partial u}{\partial \beta}  =0$$
We want to get rid of a partial to get this to being a simpler equation, and a simple way to do that is to set $b=1, a=0, d=1, c=-1$. After that I get: 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \alpha} = 0 \text{ which integrates to } u(\alpha) = C$$

and any solution to the above equation is going to be some variant on  $u=f(x-t)$. With the above values for a, b, c, d, I get $\alpha = t$ and $\beta = -x + t$. So u ends up as a function of t I would think in this case.

So far so good, but the part that the text says (and eludes me) is that it should be $u=f(\beta)$. SO your general solution here is $f(-x + t)$. It says that f is a function of $\beta$ only. Is that because using $\alpha$ you lose one variable? If I knew this I could always do the final step in these kinds of problems. I feel like I am just taking things as a given, not really understanding which (alpha or beta) I should be plugging back in. Anyhow, any help on that question would be appreciated. I did out the whole problem because I wanted to make sure my steps were right too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing only seems to make sense if you're planning to view $u$ as a function of both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. However, then you can't say "... which integrates to $u(\alpha)=C$", because "$u(\alpha)$" does not make sense: $u$ is a function of *two* variables, not one.

What's going on is that since $\partial u/\partial \alpha = 0$ everywhere, *whenever you choose some $\beta$* it must be the case that $u(1,\beta)=u(2,\beta)=u(42+\pi,\beta)=\cdots=u(\alpha,\beta)$ for all $\alpha$. In other words, changing $\alpha$ cannot change the value of $u(\alpha,\beta)$, and there must be some $f$ such that $u(\alpha,\beta)=f(\beta)$.

You lose the $\alpha$ variable exactly because $\partial u/\partial \alpha=0$ says that it does not matter.

Comment: Aha. I though it was something silly like that. I was thinking $u(\alpha)$ because it's the variable of integration in that last equation. But it's a partial derivative, right?

Comment: @Jesse: Yes -- and the use of $\partial$ instead of $d$ is exactly as a reminder that there are other variables involved too.